# generating excel sheet from database

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, apache-poi

I am trying to create excel sheet with different different values from different table in database  by using some joins my code is working but record is getting printed twice in the excel sheet i do not know i have checked everything please anyone help me here...
here is my code..

```
public class ExcelFileGen extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    String eid = (String) session.getAttribute("eid");

    try {
        String filename = "D:\\DailyWork.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("date");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("description");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Support HRS");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Development HRS");
        rowhead.createCell(4).setCellValue("training HRS");
        rowhead.createCell(5).setCellValue("Research HRS");
        rowhead.createCell(6).setCellValue("Meeting HRS");
        rowhead.createCell(7).setCellValue("leave hrs");
        rowhead.createCell(8).setCellValue("Project Name");
        rowhead.createCell(9).setCellValue("activity");
        rowhead.createCell(10).setCellValue("eid");
        rowhead.createCell(11).setCellValue("intime");
        rowhead.createCell(12).setCellValue("outtime");

        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select u.date, u.description, u.field1, u.field2, u.field3, u.field4, u.field5, u.field6, u.field7, u.activity, u.eid, d.intime, d.outtime, d.eid from updatework AS u, fulltime as d where d.eid = u.eid AND u.eid='"
                        + eid + "'");
        int i = 1;
        while (rs.next())

        {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(rs.getString("date"));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(rs.getString("description"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(rs.getString("field1"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(rs.getString("field2"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(rs.getString("field3"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(4);
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(rs.getString("field4"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(rs.getString("field5"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(6);
            row.createCell(7).setCellValue(rs.getString("field6"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(7);
            row.createCell(8).setCellValue(rs.getString("field7"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(8);
            row.createCell(9).setCellValue(rs.getString("activity"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(9);
            row.createCell(10).setCellValue(rs.getString("eid"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(10);
            row.createCell(11).setCellValue(rs.getString("intime"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(11);
            row.createCell(12).setCellValue(rs.getString("outtime"));
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(12);

            i++;
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        hwb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use other apis that can directly convert your dataset in to excel and other formats.

Comment: I suspect the select statement is returning two rows, you code looks sound

Comment: Cannot give the solution without knowing your tables, but it looks like Kenneth is right.  Please try to run your query against your database and make sure the join is returning the results you need.  By the way, think about using PreparedStatement and not concatenate parameters into the query (it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks), and think also to separe your database access code from your presentation layer (where you write your spreadsheet), just for clarity and reusability

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but `autoSizeColumn()` is a very expensive call. It should be called once all the rows have been written.

Comment: Create an answer to your question with your solution and accept it after or close your question if you don't feel like sharing the answer.

Comment: if you need a db export look at this lib to save your time https://firegloves.github.io/MemPOI/

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution everything was correct only but query was not proper now query is correct and its working ...

```
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select u.date, u.description, u.field1, u.field2, u.field3, u.field4, u.field5, u.field6, u.field7, u.activity, u.eid, d.intime, d.outtime, d.eid from updatework AS u, fulltime as d where (d.date=u.date) and (d.eid = u.eid) AND u.eid='"
                    + eid + "'");
```